# how to solve http status code -1 error

Tags: angularjs, http-status-codes

I am using an angular's http get method but whenever I load the page it throws status code -1 or 0 error response. What is the mistake I am doing here? How to resolve this ? What is the reason for this status code?

```
var requ = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://...",
    headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}
$http(requ).then(function(response){
  $scope.details=response.data.platform.record;
}, function(response){alert("failure1");alert(response.statusText);});
```

Comment: seems like CORS issue !!!

Comment: what is that cors ?how to solve it @LolCoder아카쉬

Comment: please check with including 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', inside headers

Answer (score 10):

We tend to get -1 status codes when there are network issues or connection problems, so we display the user a network problems page in those cases. It doesn't have to do with CORS as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Agree that status -1 would of network issues or connection problems. Any specific network issues you are aware?

Comment: I think just basic network connectivity, could be a multitude of reasons, like no wifi, no ethernet, lost connection, etc.

Comment: Is there Any javascript handler to access console certificates error??
net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

If these errors gets client browser, how to send these errors to developer?

Comment: Not sure I'm afraid, I think they may all result in similar error status codes. You'd have to trial and error and see what you get, but it may be hard to test these kind of responses.

Comment: HTTP status -1 is purely related to certificate error for accessing domain. It may be expired or might be certificates are not valid...
Developers can open chrome browser by adding flag --ignore-certificate-errors to skip these error, if end users faces issues, only option is renew certificates with valid certificates authorities..

Comment: It's definitely not _just_ for certificate errors, as it occurs when there's no internet connection as well. Perhaps certificate errors also result in a -1 error code though.

Comment: If this kind of errors comes at browser end, is there any a way to get control to collect browser console data programmatically with javascript

Answer (score -2):

if you use:

```
@grantolator:;3#8defect (ionic)/codebuilder\ !infection073!"73.98.12=infection {"status":-1,"code":""} UnInfect"73.98.12 apply
```

or you can use

```
.inspection."@¤=+!" In a form of (Identify.Altoffer.Complete%20") "Apply=((true))""inspect"-True=defect-" Gamerule. False
```

This should Work

Comment: This answer isn't clear. Use `code` back-ticks and punctuation.